# Revoking access to gsutil OAuth Token

Tags: gsutil

we had configured standalone gsutil on a remote server, however we do not have access to the server anymore. How do we revoke access provided to gsutil on that server. The .boto file will have the refresh Oauth2.0 token.

- we do not have access to the server and so cannot remove .boto file.
- The project configured is active in our console but we cannot see any specific access in permissions section.
- A [standalone gsutil script](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) was installed (not gcloud).

Answer (score 1):

Use gcloud auth revoke. 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke

The .gsutil directory just gets recreated within 10 seconds for me.

Answer (score 0):

OK we can revoke access to gsutil from account permissions through this link:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

[screenshot for Google Security Permissions Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMLMg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove credstore files.

```
rm -rf ~/.gsutil/
```